# why DataTable sort deosn't work on Angular 9

Tags: angular, datatable

I want to add to my datatable sort, filter, pagination options but it doesn't work for example the sort here I did every things like the tots but...

html:

```
<mat-table  [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef = "Agent" >
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="datatable_header"> Agent </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user?.Fname}} </mat-cell>

    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef = "cin">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="datatable_header"> CIN </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user?.CIN}} </mat-cell>...
```

Component:

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {


  dispalyedColumns = ['Agent','cin','email','age','role'];
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
```

...

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
```

...

```
export class User_infoDataSource extends DataSource<any>{
  sort: MatSort;  
  constructor(private CollectionService: CollectionService){
  super();}
  connect(): Observable<User_info[]>{
    this.CollectionService.getUsers().subscribe((col=>{
      console.log("data table" + col); 
    }));
    return this.CollectionService.getUsers();
  }
  disconnect(){}
}
```

module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
      DataTablesModule,
      MatTableModule,
      MatCardModule,
      MatDividerModule,
      MatSortModule,
      RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    exports: [
      RouterModule, 
      DataTablesModule,
      MatTableModule,
      MatCardModule,
      MatDividerModule,
      MatSortModule
    ]
})
```

Rq: I can see the arrows of sort, but when I click nothing happend.

Comment: reaname tag its not angular-js

Use for questions about AngularJS (1.x), the open-source JavaScript framework. Do NOT use this tag for Angular 2 or later versions; instead, use the [angular] tag.

Comment: A gentle reminder Versions 1.x == AngularJS; Versions 2+ == Angular; there is no such thing as `AngularJS 9`. Angular 9 is written in TypeScript not JS.

Comment: ok thanks for the info and how can I solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Your matColumnDef needs to match the name of the field.  So in your first column change the matColumnDef = "Agent" to matColumnDef="Fname" and update your columns to display columns accordingly.

Comment: when I change matColumnDef = "Agent" to matColumnDef="Fname"  it didin't display anythings now the datatable can't dispaly anythings

Comment: You have to change your displayed columns as well: dispalyedColumns = ['Fname','cin','email','age','role'];'